# How can I launch a python program from the desktop

Tags: python

I have written a python (3.8.5) program (TrackMyInvestments.py) using Tkinter (8.6.10). The program works fine. I want to be able to launch it from my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop. I have created a shortcut on the desktop. The code in the desktop "icon" is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
VERSION=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec='/home/bushbug/TKinterFiles/TrackMyInvestments.py'
Icon=
Name=InvestmentTracker
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
```

I have set the Permissions in the launcher's properties as Allow Executing as executable and entered chmod +x /home/bushbug/TKinterFiles/TrackMyInvestments.py in the Terminal.

When right clicking the icon I have "enabled" Allow Launching. This causes a "no-entry" sign to be shown on the icon. The problem is that when I double click the icon nothing happens. The .py file is in /home/bushbug/TKinterFiles while the desktop file is in /usr/share/applications and has a .desktop extension.
I have tried everything I could read up about creating desktop launch icons but cannot get the thing to work. Just as aside, I have a Gambas program with a desktop icon (Logbook.desktop) and when I enable its "Allow launching" the Gambas program launches so I am at a loss about the .py program.
Can anyone please help?
Kind regards.

Comment: I think you should remove quotes from the `Exec=` line. The .desktop file format does not require quoting and the quotes may be mistakenly interpreted as part of the filename ("no entry" sign you mention may be a hint to this)

Comment: Try in the .desktop file change the Exec=''/home/bushbug/TKinterFiles/TrackMyInvestments.py" to Exec=/usr/bin/python3    /home/bushbug/TKinterFiles/TrackMyInvestments.py

Comment: @yangmandi make it an answer. That is how to do it ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind, thx.

Answer (score 2):

Try in the .desktop file, change the `Exec='/home/bushbug/TKinterFiles/TrackMyInvestments.py'` to `Exec=/usr/bin/python3 /home/bushbug/TKinterFiles/TrackMyInvestments.py`

Comment: Or just add the appropriate shebang at the beginning of the .py file: `#!/usr/bin/python3`. Why do people omit this?

Comment: Thank you to all of you. yang mandi's advice worked perfectly. I cannot believe how much time I wasted trying to solve this. I will sleep happy tonight.

Comment: @raj, Yes, it's right but my answer is still working, I have tested it.

Comment: Of course it will work. But adding the appropriate "shebang" line at the beginning of a script (any script, not just Python one - it may be perl, Tcl, expect and so on...) is a "canonical" Linux/Unix method to make the script executable.